# flink jobmanger or taskmanger instances

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I had few questions in flink stream processing framework. Please let me know the your comments on these questions.

1. Let say If I build the cluster with `n` nodes, out of which I had `m` nodes as job mangers (for HA) then,  remaining nodes `(n-m)` are the ask mangers?
2. In each node, We had `n` cores then how we can control/to use the specific number of cores to task-manger/job-manger?
3. If we add the new node as task-manger then, does the job manger automatically assign the task to the newly added task-manger?
4. Does flink has concept of partitions and data skew?
5. If flink connects to pulsar and need to read the data from portioned topic. So, what is the parallelism here? (parallelism is equal to no. of partitions or it's completely depends the flink task-manager's no.of task slots)
6. Does flink has any inbuilt optimization on job graph? (Example. My job graph has so many `filter`, `map` , `flatmap`.. etc). Please can you suggest any docs/materials for flink job optimizations?
7. do we have any option like,  one dedicated core can be used for prometheus metrics scraping?

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes
2. Configuring the number of slots per TM: https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-stable/docs/concepts/flink-architecture/#task-slots-and-resources although each operator runs in its own thread and you have no control on which core they run, so you don't really have a fine-grained control of how cores are used. Configuring resource groups also allows you to distribute operators across slots: https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-stable/docs/dev/datastream/operators/overview/#task-chaining-and-resource-groups
3. Not for currently running jobs, you'd need to re-scale them. New jobs will use it though.
4. Yes. https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-stable/docs/dev/datastream/sources/
5. It will depend on the Fink source parallelism.
6. It automatically optimizes the graph as it sees fit. You have some control rescaling and chaining/splitting operators: https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-stable/docs/dev/datastream/operators/overview/ (towards the end). As a rule of thumb, I would start deploying a full job per slot and then, once properly understood where are the bottlenecks, try to optimize the graph. Most of the time is not worth it due to increased serialization and shuffling of data.
7. You can export Prometheus metrics, but not have a core dedicated to it: https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-stable/docs/deployment/metric_reporters/#prometheus